# Change Grayscale file source to jFileChooser

Tags: java, netbeans, jfilechooser, grayscale

I am working on a project that converts images to grayscale and I want to change the Source file to be user input.

this the code i am working with

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GrayScale{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;


    try{
        f = new File("F:\\test\\test.jpg");
      img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }


    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();


    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

        int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
        int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
        int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
        int b = p&0xff;


        int avg = (r+g+b)/3;


        p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

        img.setRGB(x, y, p);
      }
    }

    try{
      f = new File("F:\\test\\Output.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

So I want a way to change the try catch method for input and output to be specified by the user not standard
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [How to use file chooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)